# How to use Android HorizontalScrollView to move image one by one

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I want to create an image slider using the HorizontalScrollView. Indeed, the slider will display one image at the time and I want to be able to use the fling gesture to navigate left and right in the slider.
Any Idea to which methods to override in the HorizontalScrollView to achieve this.
Thanks a lot.
Best

Comment: dont we have Gallery view for this purpose?

Comment: Check out this answer for how to use ViewPager to achieve this : [Android ViewPager as Image Slide Gallery][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796382/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery?lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **Gallery** with **Image Switcher view** to achieve this

This Link is usefull to you for better way to implement Android **HorizontalScrollView** to move image one by one.

**Link** :http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/05/image-switcher-view-android-developer.html

**video:** http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6a6wTfSPJA

**EDIT :**
 If you want to implement **Complex** way refer this Links

1. [**Link1**](http://evgeni-shafran.blogspot.in/2011/08/tutorial-custom-gallery-circular-and.html)
2. [**Link2**](http://www.happygeek.in/customize-gallery-android)

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better served implementing this with a `Gallery` widget or a `ViewPager`.  These elements handle the display and interaction portion for you; you just have to provide the data behind that.  If these don't quite work for you, better to customize one of them then start all the way from scratch.

[Gallery Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html)

[ViewPager Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Comment: Needs to be noted: Gallery is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of below things for your need

**Gallery** - A view that shows items in a center-locked, horizontally scrolling list.

**ViewPager** -Layout manager that allows the user to flip left and right through pages of data. You supply an implementation of a PagerAdapter to generate the pages that the view 
shows.

**HorizontalScrollView** -Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display

for reference see these links - [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) , [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)