# Image navigation in android

Tags: android

I just wanted to add multiple images into android activity. And I will have to navigate that images by using next and previous buttons.. Just help me with the code that how can we store multiple images and how can we navigate them?
Thank you.

Comment: Search about Gallery and/or ViewPager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest solution is to store drawable ids in array and show one of them in ImageView. Look at this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int PREV_BUTTON_ID = 0;
    private static final int NEXT_BUTTON_ID = 1;

    private ImageView mImage;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        mImage.setImageResource(getFirstImageId());

        Button prevButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrev);
        prevButton.setId(PREV_BUTTON_ID);
        prevButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        nextButton.setId(NEXT_BUTTON_ID);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case PREV_BUTTON_ID:
                mImage.setImageResource(getPrevImageId());
                break;
            case NEXT_BUTTON_ID:
                mImage.setImageResource(getNextImageId());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private static final int[] sImages = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3 };

    private int mCurrentImageId;

    private int getFirstImageId() {
        return sImages[mCurrentImageId];
    }

    private int getNextImageId() {
        mCurrentImageId++;

        if (mCurrentImageId > sImages.length - 1) {
            mCurrentImageId = sImages.length - 1;
        }

        return sImages[mCurrentImageId];
    }

    private int getPrevImageId() {
        mCurrentImageId--;

        if (mCurrentImageId < 0) {
            mCurrentImageId = 0;
        }

        return sImages[mCurrentImageId];
    }
}
```

and layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Prev"
            android:id="@+id/btnPrev"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement image navigation, you could use the official [**Android ViewPager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

However, you might like a more customised [**ViewPagerIndicator**](http://viewpagerindicator.com/), by Jake Wharton.

Plus, you could get a lot of help from this existing [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796382/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery).