# how can i achieve transition like animation for an object,within an activity?

Tags: android, android-animation

Hello first of all i am a newbie, and Like we achieve transition in the fragments with the help of  View pager and an adapter  how can we achieve transition within an activity, i mean how can i setup a horizontal row of images and swipe them,for the next or previous image to appear? i want 3-5(out of many) images visible  at the same time and one of them should be centered,i don't want the code.... just i don't know what should i be looking for?

Comment: it's good if you use ViewFlipper. You can easily setup your images in one xml file and filp them as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want something like an image gallery pager. You can check Jake Wharthon's [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) which I am also using that you can customise the ui according to your images. You can also try checking [GalleryViewPager](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android-Open-Source-App/Media/AndroidTouchGallery/ru/truba/touchgallery/GalleryWidget/GalleryViewPager.java.htm) for a gallery with zoom functionality.

Here is another stackoverflow topic with many examples that you can try:
[Android Viewpager as Image Slide Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796382/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery)

updated answer 1: [TwoWayGridView](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview)  the image you posted in a scrollable GridView so you can use this library with horizontal swiping.

updated answer 2: Use this [HorizontalScrollView](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/07/implement-gallery-like.html) example and implement rotation animation for images except the one in the center by overriding some functions inside. I don't know of a ready code which does this kind of animated view as you wanted so this is the first thing I am thought how to do it.

Comment: Isn't the ViewPagerIndicator for fragments?

Comment: i am  trying to achieve something like this

Comment: Ohh I see. I thought you wanted a single row gallery. Updating my answer now.

Comment: sorry i gave you the wrong link

Comment: wait a minute.. please

Comment: http://www.google.co.in/imgres?start=175&safe=off&sa=X&biw=1366&bih=643&tbm=isch&tbnid=-qIXIf0yLCk9mM:&imgrefurl=http://kootation.com/korea-music-android-apps-and-tests-androidpit.html&docid=Vrq1kZUuZA8TCM&imgurl=http://fs01.androidpit.info/ass/x43/2124443-1304427663535.jpg&w=854&h=480&ei=iZIMUveSFY-akgWXxYG4DQ&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:3,s:200,i:13&iact=rc&page=7&tbnh=168&tbnw=281&ndsp=32&tx=231&ty=26#imgdii=_

Comment: i am sorry i gave you the wrong link....above this comment is the proper link

Comment: No problem I gave another link hope it helps you

Comment: Thanx..will i have to merge it with animation to obtain the desired effect?

Comment: yes you should use a horizontal rotate animation for the images that you want.