# How to create an image slider?

Tags: android, slider

How to create an image slider in eclipse?

i want, when a finger moves from left to right or from right to left on imageView, I want to  change the photo.

Comment: use view pager to slide images. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796382/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery

Comment: For this you have to use gallery or view-pager and after you can do code as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

No need to do any custom thing.As Android provides the facility like this in ViewFlipper class.It is actually made for it.

#### View Flipper:-

> Simple ViewAnimator that will animate between two or more views that
>   have  been added to it. Only one child is shown at a time. If
>   requested, can  automatically flip between each child at a regular
>   interval.

Its very nice and also built in support for animation so just use this for this purpose.
To implement the ViewFlipper in your application I am sharing some good tutorials..

http://javatechig.com/android/android-viewflipper-example

http://www.yogeshblogspot.com/android-viewflipper-example/

http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/06/android-viewflipper-example.html

You can also get more info at here.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html.

Enjoy..!

Answer (score 0):

View Pager [refer  this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)  is one option, otherwise you can add a simple gesture listener to your image view.

//Adding gesture listener to image view.

```
final GestureDetector gdt = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());
        final ImageView imageView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
                gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }
        });
```

//The gesture listener class

```
  private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
//load previous image here
                    return false; // Right to left
                }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
//load next image here
                    return false; // Left to right
                }

                if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    return false; // Bottom to top
                }  else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    return false; // Top to bottom
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```