# I want to implement image slider

Tags: android

[image]
[image]

How can i implement image slider in android that shows some part of next and previous image as shown in image.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796382/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery

Comment: @Sushil gallery is decripted now

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz .. yes you are correct. it is deprecated. using View pager is a better idea. Using some opensource coverflow view is also good idea.

Comment: @Sushil I was not knowing about Coverflow.i just checked it ,its pretty interesting

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz .. yes I used a couple of them in different projects and really liked them. I will post it as answer with few links :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try horizontal listview for this

https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android

Answer (score 2):

You can use some opensource Coverflow widget to accomplish your task. By this you can make it look more eye candy and can have more features.

One of them is:

https://code.google.com/p/android-coverflow/

Comment: I saw this in many app but was never able to figure it out how to so

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz If you google, you will get few open source projects who have done good and simple implementations. You can pick one and its easy to modify as per your need.