# Image Sliding and Async Task for each item

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager

I want to slide through a gallery and for each image to get some details using an async task .

It is a simple View Pager the best solution or should I use fragments instead?

The async task should be called in instantiate item or to add a listener on page changed and add there ?

Comment: refer this link : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html#viewpager

Answer (score 2):

You should use ViewPager and if you want circled view below it use circled pager indicateor in contrast to view pager.

Below are some links it will help you lot.

http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/

https://coderwall.com/p/uz-s8g

http://blog.gaku.net/fast-viewpager-with-images/

https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGalleryhttp://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-image-fragment-pager-view/

Have a lok at this too previously answered in stackoverflow how to use.They used scherlock fragment you just took concept of view pager from here and use.. support fragment
[Android Viewpager as Image Slide Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796382/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery)