# How works photoView in Facebook android application?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

How works this view in Facebook android app?
I want to do view in my app like this.
Does anyone have any sources or examples?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is Viewpager widget inside your fragment/activity.

See [Viewpager as image slide gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796382/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery)

Comment: No,no. I asked about photoview which opened by click on image.

Comment: based on this http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Replace ImageView by your Viewpager.