# How to set boundary for moving views in android

Tags: android, layout, view, ontouchlistener

how can we limit views inside the parent layout in android till now I am able to move views on touch event but I want to limit those views inside parent layout

Comment: write down a boundary collision detection check!

Comment: use "View Pager" concept.

Comment: can you please explain little more about how could I do that @MuhammadBabar

Comment: refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796382/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery)

Comment: you know that your bounds are 0(x) left most, screenWidth(x) right most, 0(y) top most, screenHeight(y) bottom most. Now create a logic and check if your views bound are colliding them then don't move further.

Comment: I already did that but not working proper @MuhammadBabar thats why i am here for a refine logic