# How to display the images from Horizontal scroll view In android as slide view using picasso

Tags: android, json

I have an horizontal scroll views for different categories of images. On click of image thumbnail it will display that image. Now on click of thumbnail need to display the image along with slide view.

How to do this?. Now am able to display single image at once on click of thumbnail. Am using picasso to do this.

please help me out. Am getting the data(image url) as json response from server.

Comment: See this [tutorial](http://androhub.com/android-image-slider-using-viewpager/). In this remove circle page indicator and use put your images array to display as many images.

Comment: @SurenderKumar My requirement is different , I have horizontal scroll view of images. By clicking on some image it should display, and on slide it should display next image .

Comment: I am also saying the same thing when a single image is opening then that single image will be over ViewPager and you have to save images array for ViewPager to display next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should use ViewPager for Horizontally showing pictures.**

Comment: I have already displayed images in horizontal scroll view. But my question is i need to view them as slide view after on click of the image.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796382/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery

Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html)

Every time You can Create New object of `ImageView` like

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

and add that image inside `HorizontalScrollView`.
and then you can load image like.

```
Picasso.with(this)
 .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")        
 .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder)   // optional        
 .error(R.drawable.ic_error_fallback)      // optional        
 .resize(250, 200)                        // optional        
 .rotate(90)                             // optional        
 .into(imageView);
```

Comment: This code will display only the current image that we click. I need to display all images on click of some images in slide view.