# How to show images with horizontal scrolling android

Tags: android, gallery

I am using a Recyclerview to show the list of items. Now each time can have some photos/multiple photos which I need to show with horizontal scrolling in a single row.

I am currently using Gallery widget to show the photos but as it is now deprecated, so I want some other thing to use to show images horizontally with same features as Gallery have. Can you please help me here.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the example of horizontal scrollable RecycleView showing bitmap images:

**fragment/activity layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       ...

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        />
            ...

</LinearLayout>
```

**item:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_item_view_image"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_width="109dp"
    android:layout_height="109dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**adapter:**

```
public class HorizontalPhotosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalPhotosAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView riv;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            riv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_item_view_image);

        }
    }


    public HorizontalPhotosAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmapList, String[] imageUrls) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bitmapList = bitmapList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.horizontal_item_view, parent, false);

        if (itemView.getLayoutParams ().width == RecyclerView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            itemView.getLayoutParams ().width = RecyclerView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.riv.setImageBitmap(bitmapList.get(position));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bitmapList.size();
    }
}
```

**implementation in fragment/activity:**

```
            horizontalAdapter=new HorizontalPhotosAdapter(getContext(), bitmapList);
            horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
            horizontalAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManagaer = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
            horizontal_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManagaer);
            horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);
```

Comment: Working like a charm your code + Glide library to load & cache images

Comment: Glad it help. You can upvote answer so it could be more relevant as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HorizontalScrollView or ViewPager for your purpose.

[Android Viewpager as Image Slide Gallery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796382/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewpager to implement slide show gallery

follow link -

http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/

Answer (score 0):

A LayoutManager is responsible for measuring and positioning item views within a RecyclerView as well as determining the policy for when to recycle item views that are no longer visible to the user. By changing the LayoutManager a RecyclerView can be used to implement a standard vertically scrolling list, a uniform grid, staggered grids, horizontally scrolling collections and more. Several stock layout managers are provided for general use.

Try the below code to get recycler view with horizontal item

```
    LinearLayoutManager ll_manager= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    ll_manager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llmRecent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following piece of code:

```
GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```