# How to do Onboarding in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

How to do such a thing as the picture when you first start the application? Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796382/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create an onboarding screen or slides to introduce the basic functions of your app. There are different ways to achieve this.

[This Github Tutorial](https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-Onboarding) may help you.